# Find the range and inverse of $\log(z^2+1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

This was a three part problem. In the first part I showed that for $A=\{z:\Re(z)>0\}$ that the function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ given by $f(z)=\mathrm{Log}(z^2+1)$ was univalent. (Log here is defined as the principal log).

Now I am trying to find the range of $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$.

For the range, I broke $f$ down into its components $g(z)=z^2$, $h(z)=z+1$ and $l(z)=\mathrm{Log}(z)$. For the function $g$, I saw that for any $z\in A$, if $z=x+iy$ and $x>0$ then $z^2=(x^2-y^2)+i2xy$ where $(x^2-y^2)$ and $2xy$ can be any number in $\mathbb{R}$ so $g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. For $h\circ g=z^2+1$ I thought that since $z^2\in\mathbb{C}$ then it followed that $z^2+1\in\mathbb{C}+1$ so $h\circ g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}+1$. Finally, since $\mathbb{C}+1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ we have $\mathrm{Log}(z^2+1)$ unrestricted on the real axis but since it is the principal log it is bounded on the imaginary axis in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.

For the inverse function I let $w=\mathrm{Log}(z^2+1)$. Then

$$
e^w=z^2+1\Leftrightarrow e^w-1=z^2\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{e^w-1}=z
$$

where

$$
\sqrt{e^w-1}=\sqrt{|e^w-1|}\left[\cos\left(\frac{\arg(e^w-1)}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\arg(e^w-1)}{2}\right)\right]
$$

if $\sqrt{|e^w-1|}\cos\left(\frac{\arg(e^w-1)}{2}\right)>0$ or

$$ 
\sqrt{e^w-1}=\sqrt{|e^w-1|}\left[\cos\left(\frac{\arg(e^w-1)}{2}+\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\arg(e^w-1)}{2}+\pi\right)\right]
$$

if $\sqrt{|e^w-1|}\cos\left(\frac{\arg(e^w-1)}{2}+\pi\right)>0$.

I am particularly worried about the range of $\mathrm{Log}(z^2+1)$ because for the range that I found, we could possibly have $w=0$ which would present a problem for the inverse function that I found where $z$ cannot be equal to 0.

Comment: Actually $h\circ g(A) = \{z\in\mathbb C : \Re z > 0 \vee \Im z \neq 1\}$. You can remove $\{z\in\mathbb C : \Re z = 0 \wedge \Im z \in [0,1] \} = "[0,i]"$ from this to get a "slash" from $0$ to $\infty$ and thus to be able to invert $\log(z^2+1)$ in that region.

Comment: Why is $\Re(z)>0$ for the range of $h\circ g(A)$? Couldn't $x^2-y^2$ be any value in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Note the $\vee$. It says, if $\Im z = 1$ then $\Re z > 0$ or it's not in the image.

Comment: You are omitting a branch of the square root: $e^w-1=z^2\Leftrightarrow z = \pm \sqrt{e^w-1} $

Comment: @AlexR I am a little confused with the notation. I am reading it as $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Re(z)>0$ or $\Im(z)\not=1$.

Comment: @ImNotReallyHere That's true. And now try to draw this set.

Comment: @gammatester I believe the $+\pi$ within the trig functions corrects for that.

Comment: @AlexR When I draw this set, I get either the plane is divided by the line $\Im(z)=1$ or I get the half of the plane where $\Re(z)>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z^2$ maps $A$ onto $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$

here you missed that if $a=x^2-y^2$ and $b=2xy=0$ then $y=0$ and therefore $a>0$

$z^2+1$ maps $A$ onto $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,1]$

Since $\operatorname{Log}$ is a biholomorphic map 
$$
\operatorname{Log}:  \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0] \rightarrow 
\mathbb \{z\in \mathbb C : -\pi < \operatorname{Im}z< \pi \}
$$
you see that the range of $\operatorname{Log(z^2+1)}$ is the set
$$
\{z\in \mathbb C : -\pi < \operatorname{Im}z< \pi \}
\setminus \operatorname{Log}((0,1])=
\{z\in \mathbb C : -\pi < \operatorname{Im}z< \pi \}
\setminus (-\infty,0]
$$

Comment: What if $y>x$? Couldn't we then have $a<0$?

Comment: Yes, any $x+iy$ having $y>x>0$ is in $z^2(A)$, but in that case $2xy>0$

Comment: You can solve $x^2-y^2=a$, $2xy=b$ always with a pair $(x,y)$ such that $x>0$ if $b\neq 0$!

Comment: Then wouldn't $z^2$ maps A onto $\mathbb{C}\backslash(-\infty,0]$ be excluding that?

Comment: Just show that $F(x,y):A \rightarrow \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$ given by $F(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is injective and surjective...

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't see why $z^2$ can't take on every value of the complex plane. Am I reading the notation wrong? I'm seeing $\mathbb{C}\backslash(-\infty,0]$ as every point of the complex plane with $\Re(z)>0$. The way I see it, if we let $a=\Re(z)$ then since $y$ can be any value in $\mathbb{R}$ we can have $a\leq 0$ and so $\Re(z)\in(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: No, we remove a half-line from $\mathbb C$: $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]=\{x+iy | y\neq 0 \text { or } x>0\}$ is the complex plane with the negative real axis and 0 deleted.

Comment: AHHHHHH! OK! Yes. That makes a lot more sense now and now that I've gotten the notation right everything is making sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might find this picture to be illustrative:  [image: Mapping of $f(z) = \log(z^2+1)$ for $\Re(z) > 0$]

The picture maps the positive real half-disk $\{re^{i\theta} : r > 0, -\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} \}$ to $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus (-\infty, 0]$.  Lines indicate curves of constant $|z|$ or $\arg(z)$.  Hue is argument; saturation and brightness indicate magnitude.

The Mathematica code used to generate this picture is as follows:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} &[Log[(r Exp[I t])^2 + 1]], 
     {r, .001, 5}, {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
     PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
     Mesh -> {30, 30}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[v,
     1/(0.25 + 3 Log[u + 1]), 1 - 1/(1.1 + 10 Log[u + 1])]]]
```